# Dynamically create object with properties based on inputted List C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, object

I have a method that takes in two arrays of integers as parameters. I want to dynamically create objects based on the input. So if user puts in [2,3] and [4,3,2],  I want to create 3 new Objects ( Friend2, Friend3 , Friend4).
I have 2 issues I am stuck with:

- Dynamically creating multiple objects with different names based on list items
- Iterating through two lists and selecting only distinct values of both lists.

  ```
      static int maxTokens( int[] friends_from, int[] friends_to){

  **-- Need Code Here  to iterate through both arrays and create distinct objects**

  foreach (var Friend in  friends_from and  friends_To)
      {
          Friend  intFriend[i] = new Friend();
      }
    }
  ```

  Is there a way to use Linq to (If not what is the best way to accomplish this?):
- Save myself from iterating through two lists adding both of them to a third list and selecting distinct
- dynamically create object with distinct Name based on listItem

Comment: The requirement is unclear. So you have arrays of integers, and you want to create a sequence of Friends. The contents of the Friends are not influenced by the actual numbers in the arrays? The arrays only influence  the number of friends in your result sequence? So if you have array 2, 4, 8 and array  4, 6, 7 you want as a result an array with nothing in [0] [1] [3] [5] and only Friends in [2] [4] [6] [7] [8]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use union operation to get an array of distinct values like below and then create your object as required

```
 static int maxTokens( int[] friends_from, int[] friends_to)
 {
     var uniqueFriends = friends_from.Union(friends_to).ToArray();

     foreach (var Friend in  uniqueFriends)
     {
        // add your logic for creating instance
     }
  }
```

Comment: This works for first part of question! Now I just need to create instance.

Comment: Creating a new instance is easy, but what do you want to do with that instance determines how you handle the created instance.